# Where can I find a Swift dictionary of all country codes in iTunes

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, itunes

Where can I find a Swift dictionary of all country codes in iTunes? For example, something like this:

`let countryCodes=["CA":"Canada","FI":"Finland"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right here:

```
let countryCodes=["AE":"United Arab Emirates",
        "AG":"Antigua and Barbuda",
        "AI":"Anguilla",
        "AL":"Albania",
        "AM":"Armenia",
        "AO":"Angola",
        "AR":"Argentina",
        "AT":"Austria",
        "AU":"Australia",
        "AZ":"Azerbaijan",
        "BB":"Barbados",
        "BE":"Belgium",
        "BF":"Burkina Faso",
        "BG":"Bulgaria",
        "BH":"Bahrain",
        "BJ":"Benin",
        "BM":"Bermuda",
        "BN":"Brunei",
        "BO":"Bolivia",
        "BR":"Brazil",
        "BS":"Bahamas",
        "BT":"Bhutan",
        "BW":"Botswana",
        "BY":"Belarus",
        "BZ":"Belize",
        "CA":"Canada",
        "CG":"Republic Of Congo",
        "CH":"Switzerland",
        "CL":"Chile",
        "CN":"China",
        "CO":"Colombia",
        "CR":"Costa Rica",
        "CV":"Cape Verde",
        "CY":"Cyprus",
        "CZ":"Czech Republic",
        "DE":"Germany",
        "DK":"Denmark",
        "DM":"Dominica",
        "DO":"Dominican Republic",
        "DZ":"Algeria",
        "EC":"Ecuador",
        "EE":"Estonia",
        "EG":"Egypt",
        "ES":"Spain",
        "FI":"Finland",
        "FJ":"Fiji",
        "FM":"Federated States Of Micronesia",
        "FR":"France",
        "GB":"United Kingdom",
        "GD":"Grenada",
        "GH":"Ghana",
        "GM":"Gambia",
        "GR":"Greece",
        "GT":"Guatemala",
        "GW":"Guinea-Bissau",
        "GY":"Guyana",
        "HK":"Hong Kong",
        "HN":"Honduras",
        "HR":"Croatia",
        "HU":"Hungary",
        "ID":"Indonesia",
        "IE":"Ireland",
        "IL":"Israel",
        "IN":"India",
        "IS":"Iceland",
        "IT":"Italy",
        "JM":"Jamaica",
        "JO":"Jordan",
        "JP":"Japan",
        "KE":"Kenya",
        "KG":"Kyrgyzstan",
        "KH":"Cambodia",
        "KN":"St. Kitts and Nevis",
        "KR":"Republic Of Korea",
        "KW":"Kuwait",
        "KY":"Cayman Islands",
        "KZ":"Kazakstan",
        "LA":"Lao People’s Democratic Republic",
        "LB":"Lebanon",
        "LC":"St. Lucia",
        "LK":"Sri Lanka",
        "LR":"Liberia",
        "LT":"Lithuania",
        "LU":"Luxembourg",
        "LV":"Latvia",
        "MD":"Republic Of Moldova",
        "MG":"Madagascar",
        "MK":"Macedonia",
        "ML":"Mali",
        "MN":"Mongolia",
        "MO":"Macau",
        "MR":"Mauritania",
        "MS":"Montserrat",
        "MT":"Malta",
        "MU":"Mauritius",
        "MW":"Malawi",
        "MX":"Mexico",
        "MY":"Malaysia",
        "MZ":"Mozambique",
        "NA":"Namibia",
        "NE":"Niger",
        "NG":"Nigeria",
        "NI":"Nicaragua",
        "NL":"Netherlands",
        "NO":"Norway",
        "NP":"Nepal",
        "NZ":"New Zealand",
        "OM":"Oman",
        "PA":"Panama",
        "PE":"Peru",
        "PG":"Papua New Guinea",
        "PH":"Philippines",
        "PK":"Pakistan",
        "PL":"Poland",
        "PT":"Portugal",
        "PW":"Palau",
        "PY":"Paraguay",
        "QA":"Qatar",
        "RO":"Romania",
        "RU":"Russia",
        "SA":"Saudi Arabia",
        "SB":"Solomon Islands",
        "SC":"Seychelles",
        "SE":"Sweden",
        "SG":"Singapore",
        "SI":"Slovenia",
        "SK":"Slovakia",
        "SL":"Sierra Leone",
        "SN":"Senegal",
        "SR":"Suriname",
        "ST":"Sao Tome and Principe",
        "SV":"El Salvador",
        "SZ":"Swaziland",
        "TC":"Turks and Caicos",
        "TD":"Chad",
        "TH":"Thailand",
        "TJ":"Tajikistan",
        "TM":"Turkmenistan",
        "TN":"Tunisia",
        "TR":"Turkey",
        "TT":"Trinidad and Tobago",
        "TW":"Taiwan",
        "TZ":"Tanzania",
        "UA":"Ukraine",
        "UG":"Uganda",
        "US":"United States",
        "UY":"Uruguay",
        "UZ":"Uzbekistan",
        "VC":"St. Vincent and The Grenadines",
        "VE":"Venezuela",
        "VG":"British Virgin Islands",
        "VN":"Vietnam",
        "YE":"Yemen",
        "ZA":"South Africa",
        "ZW":"Zimbabwe"]
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html

Comment: You should mention that Apple provides a list at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html. It may change in the future.